# How to get user data out of PayPalAuthorization

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I installed the PayPal SDK 2.13.3, set up client id, environment, etc. I activated the `Log In with PayPal` for my app in the dashboard.

Now the code:

```
PayPalAuthorization auth = data.getParcelableExtra( PayPalProfileSharingActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION );
JSONObject json = auth.toJSONObject();
Logg.i( this, "payPal auth = " + json );
```

gives out the result like:

```
{"client":{"environment":"sandbox","paypal_sdk_version":"2.13.3","platform":"Android","product_name":"PayPal-Android-SDK"},"response":{"code":"blablah"},"response_type":"authorization_code"}
```

I'd like to get the fields defined as scopes here:

```
Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( PAYPAL_SCOPE_OPENID, PAYPAL_SCOPE_PROFILE, PAYPAL_SCOPE_EMAIL ) );
i.putExtra( PayPalProfileSharingActivity.EXTRA_REQUESTED_SCOPES, new PayPalOAuthScopes( scopes ) );
```

What's the way to accomplish that? Should I issue another request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after doing some research it appears, that the best way to implement the PayPal login is to port the 2nd part on the server.

After getting `user content` on the device and `"response":{"code":"blablah"}`, it's best to send the `code` to the server where the following requests should take place:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "{client-id}:{secret}" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

and then:

```
curl 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token' \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -H "Authorization: Basic QWZVa...==" \
    -d 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=MFYQ...'
```

as per http://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/profile_sharing_server.md and http://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/#get-an-access-token